# Altium Designer - Design Variants

Tags: schematics, altium

Is there a way to make Altium Designer show design variants on "Editor" tab?

For example, if I define a new design variant, any components that I mark as not-fitted or alternate part are visible only in "Schematic" tab (sheet name is Schematic).

I've attached two images below where you can see what I'm talking about.
I've searched through Altium's design resources and couldn't find how to do this.

[image: Looking at Editor, all components are fitted. Even thou variant is selected]

[image: Looking at Schematic, not fitted components are marked as DNP.]

I would like to have DNP components always shown. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Version 18 or earlier?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't believe you can, the "Editor" is used for designing the overall circuit and ignores the variants. You really need to look at the other tab in order to see the variant-specific schematic.

Comment: That's what I was thinking after I did some research but wasn't 100% sure if it's true. Thanks